# How to know what is slowing down a MySql left join

Tags: php, mysql, join

I created a view that is a join between two tables a.2_9 (18.483 rows) and b.2_10 (5700 rows)

it is a very simple join:

```
 Create view v_2_9_join_2_10 AS
 Select *
 FROM 2_9 AS a
 LEFT JOIN 2_10 b
   ON a.2_9_tid = b.2_10_tid
   AND a.2_9_region = b.2_10_region
   AND a.n_2 = b.n_2
```

I to create the view and count the rows (18483) but for some reason it takes forever when I try to use the view, count or export or just browse and it is slowing down the database in PHP too much.

Any ideas of how I can look for the reason(s) of the slowing down or optimize the join?

Comment: The point about using EXPLAIN raised by @Gori below is a good one. However MySQL doesn't take advantage of indexes when accessing the results of a view (ie, the view itself uses indexes, but not your query of the resulting data - not a major problem if the view returns a small number of rows but can be an issue if it returns a large number of rows).

Answer (score 0):

To know why a query is being slow you can issue the query you used to create the view with the [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) keyword, this will show a little table with data that explains how MySQL executed the query so you can identify the bottlenecks there.

[HERE](http://www.sitepoint.com/using-explain-to-write-better-mysql-queries/) you can find a little tutorial on how to understand the output of `EXPLAIN`.

Comment: Thanks  lot! I need to improve the structure of the tables, since I am not using indexing the "type" is "ALL" and therefore is looking at all of the rows.

Comment: @carla Glad I could help! :)